# WPF DataGrid : TemplateColumn with UserControl and TextBlock

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

Im a bit stuck here.. been searching for two days and found no solution.

What i would like to achieve is the behavior of `DataGridComboBoxColumn` .
I need its `DisplayMemberPath`, `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValueBinding` properties..

Im having my UserControl similar to ComboBox in the `CellEditingTemplate`
and TextBlock in `CellTemplate`.

Im doing all these in code, since these columns may not exist necessarily..

This is where i define the TemplateColumn :

```
DataGridTemplateColumn tcol = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
tcol.Header = "accCust";

FrameworkElementFactory texttablF = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextTableBox));
texttablF.SetValue(TextTableBox.TableSourceProperty, accTable.DefaultView);

FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
texttablF.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Account"));


tcol.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataGridCell)) { VisualTree = tb };
tcol.CellEditingTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataGridCell)) { VisualTree = texttablF };
```

I have two issues :

1. TextBlock shows the ID present in the DataGrid's Table, I want it to show the value specified in the `DisplayMemberPath`, which i have no idea how to implement.
2. The DependencyProperty `TableSource` isnt working when done via FrameworkElement.setValue.. It works when it is done in the normal way,
   ie

   ```
   TextTableBox ttb = new TextTableBox();
   ttb.TableSource = src_table.DefaultView;
   ```

I hope its clear to you what my problem is.. All i really want is to replace the ComboBox in DataGridComboColumn with my UserControl..

Thanks in advance :)
Im sorry if it is a poor question.. Im new to WPF and doing my HighSchools..

Comment: What is TextTableBox?

Comment: That is my UserControl.. :)

Comment: It would be good to get some more info on it. For example - where it's inherited from?

Comment: TextTableBox is a control much similar to ComboBox control except its Popus shows a DataGrid instead of a list of items in a StackPanel. The control is inherited from UserControl class, not ComboBox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i wanted the Properties of ComboBox, i had to inherit from `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

Heres how the code looks like :

```
public class DataGridTCBColumn : DataGridComboBoxColumn
{
    private TableComboBox comboBox;

    public DataGridTCBColumn(bool Editable)
    {
        comboBox = new TableComboBox() { IsEditable = Editable };
    }

    // Requires extra field..
    public string SelectedValuePathX
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(SelectedValuePathXProperty);
        }
        set
        {

            this.SetValue(SelectedValuePathXProperty, value);

        }
    }
    static FrameworkPropertyMetadata SelectedValuePathXPropertyMeta = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(SelectedValuePathXPropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValuePathXProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValueX", typeof(string), typeof(TableComboBox), SelectedValuePathXPropertyMeta);
    private static void SelectedValuePathXPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dobj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {}

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Property == DataGridTCBColumn.ItemsSourceProperty)
        {
            comboBox.ItemsSource = ItemsSource;
        }
        else if (e.Property == DataGridTCBColumn.SelectedValuePathProperty)
        {
            comboBox.SelectedValuePath = SelectedValuePath;
        }
        else if (e.Property == DataGridTCBColumn.DisplayMemberPathProperty)
        {
            comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = DisplayMemberPath;
        }

        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }


    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        return comboBox;
    }
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = editingEventArgs.Source as DataGridCell;
        if (cell != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SelectedValuePathX))
        {
            //For Typed DataSet
            object obj = ((DataRowView)editingElement.DataContext).Row[this.SelectedValuePathX];
            comboBox.SelectedValue = obj;
        }

        comboBox.Focus();
        return comboBox.SelectedItem;
    }
    protected override bool CommitCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement)
    {   
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SelectedValuePathX) && comboBox.SelectedValue != null)
        ((DataRowView)editingElement.DataContext).Row[this.SelectedValuePathX] = comboBox.SelectedValue;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Had to make another dependency propertry `SelectedValuePathX`. Actually, it does the job of `SelectedValueBinding`. However that Binding never did work (tried goin through the source code of ComboBox ([Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs,2ba9dd6838416d6a)) but dint work out well either.

Hopes it would help somebody :)